# Where does an SQL DBA get himself educated on ASP.NET app creation in VS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

As an SQL Server DBA, I have still had many a side opportunity to create mini applications in MS Access, which over time, have become quite hefty and feature laden. I would like to get myself trained in C# and ASP.NET so I could graduate these applications to the professional level. I have Visual Studio 2010 Pro and want to get rolling. Where could I find a good source for educational material?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the official Microsoft resources for web development (videos and tutorials):

http://asp.net

And

http://asp.net/mvc

A good starter book for C# is [Head First C#](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Head-First-C-Andrew-Stellman/dp/0596514824).

Comment: +1 The MVC website posted by @Oded is the de-facto standard. You will find the latest info here from the Microsoft team.